# Authentication Failed while using Azure AD Bearer Token, to return list of containers [Azure Blob] [Azure AD OAuth 2.0] [REST API]

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, rest

I have successfully tried performing authentication using the `Shared key` and then make *`REST calls`* to *`Azure Blob`*.
Now I am trying to Authenticate using *`AzureAD OAuth 2.0`*, to receive a Bearer token and pass that for *`Authentication`* to make  *`REST calls`*.
I am successfully getting the `Bearer token` but unable to perform authentication.

**Here's the code:**

```
const request = require("request");
require("dotenv").config();

const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const key = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";
const tenantId = process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID || "";
const clientId = process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID || "";
const clientSecret = process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET || "";

const options = {
  url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  formData: {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    // scope:"http://storage.azure.com/.default",
    client_secret: clientSecret,
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
  },
};

var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();

function callback(error, response, body) {
  const options = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list`,

    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(response.body).access_token}`,
      "x-ms-date": strTime,
      "x-ms-version": "2019-02-02",
    },
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("Response is: ", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage);
  });
}

request(options, callback);
```

It shows Auth failed when I try to run it.

```
 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

[image: ScreenShot of Output]

**Here are some links for Reference:**
[Service-Service calls using client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN),
[OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

**EDIT:** The scope was tried for both the links, options url updated from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Screenshot of Access Control.
[image: SS of Access Control(IAM)]

But still, the same error persists.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad? Your Service Principal need to have additional roles in order to access data plane API (list containers for example) + the scope will be different as well.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,' ?  v2.0 here.

Comment: The link you provided uses v2.0 version, and your code hasn't used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `scope` with `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/.default` or `https://storage.azure.com/.default`.

**Notes:**

1. scope is supported in "v2.0". If you use v1.0, `scope` needs to be replaced with `resource`, code looks like `resource: "https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/"`.
2. When using formData, you must set "multipart/form-data".
3. Navigate to Azure storage -> Access control(IAM) -> **Add role assignment** to add a service principal to your storage account

[image]

Code:

```
const request = require("request");
require("dotenv").config();
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

const account = "";
const key = "";
const tenantId = "";
const clientId = "";
const clientSecret = "";

const postData = {
  client_id: clientId,
  scope: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/.default`,
  client_secret: clientSecret,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials'
};

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

let token = '';

axios.post(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, qs.stringify(postData))
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    token = response.data.access_token;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on what exactly you mean by "add a service principal to your account" I have updated the above question with ss of Azure Portal Access Control(IAM), have a look and let me know what am I missing.

Comment: Hi, @MayankPatel. I add the screenshot in my reply. pamelaTestApplication is the application used to authenticate.

Comment: I have added Mayank Test Registration App as Storage Blob Data Contributor, and the same app is used to generate ClientID, ClientSecret, TenantID, but still the same Auth Failed error.

Comment: Sorry, the scope should be `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/.default`. I confused it with other flows:(  And you could POST for access token, I have shared the code in my answer. I refer to this [document](https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-get-an-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-using-node-js-258723f29cc6).

Comment: It solved the problem @Pamela, I have accepted your answer. Thanks