# Authorization Permission Mismatch when trying to PUT a file in Azure Blob with AD token/ Bearer Token[Azure-Blob][Bearer-Token]

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, bearer-token

I am able to **CreateContainers, ListContainers, ListBlobs** but when I am trying to make a `PUT/DELETE` request to **upload** or **delete** files in the Azure Storage blob but it shows the following error after making the request:

```
403
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
{
  'content-length': '279',
  'content-type': 'application/xml',
  server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
  'x-ms-request-id': '4de6c154-f01e-0051-7ce4-1314ef000000',
  'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28',
  'x-ms-error-code': 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch',
  date: 'Mon, 08 Mar 2021 06:32:44 GMT',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

The code for `upload/PUT` file is:

```
const request = require("request");
require("dotenv").config();

const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const containerName = "demo";
const blobName = "dummyfile1.txt";
const blobContent = "Hello, This will be written in file";
const contentLength = new TextEncoder().encode(blobContent).length;

var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <BearerToken>",
    "x-ms-date": strTime,
    "x-ms-version": "2018-03-28",
    "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
    "Content-Length": contentLength,
    "Content-Type": 'application/text-plain',
  },
  body: blobContent,
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.statusMessage);
  console.log(response.headers);
}

request.put(options, callback);
```

**Here I am manually replacing the  from the one which I am getting through POSTMAN via:**

[image: POSTMAN call to get ACCESS TOKEN]

**Also, I have added the permission of Storage Data Contributor to the App:**

[image: Access Control IAM]

**I have delegated Azure Storage, user_impersonation permission also to the Application.**
[image: Azure Storage user_impersonation]

But still, the same error persists.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66488056/13308381) uses client credentials flow. But you use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) in this issue. Try to add [Azure Storage permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XniAN.png) and use `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation offline_access` scope.

Comment: @Pamela I tried using `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation offline_access` to access Bearer Token via POSTMAN and use that bearer token to run this request.
But still, it gives the same error message. 
Yes, Also in the previous question, I was trying to get the Bearer token via client credentials here I am trying to get it via Auth Code flow.
Note: I have given the Storage Blob data contributor to the app.

Comment: You should add Azure Storage delegate permission in the portal, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/XniAN.png. I have tried your code, it's correct.

Comment: I had already specified Azure Storage delegated permission as user_impersonation, but still the same error, I have added the screenshot in the question update.

Comment: It's weird. I will add the detailed steps about access token later.

Comment: @Pamela I am able to ListContainer, ListBlobs, CreateContainer using that Bearer Token. But I am not able to Create a Blob, Delete a Blob, GetBlob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), the permission of Azure Storage is required for your signed-in user. When using `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role, you need to add role assignment to **your account** but not application(only client credentials flow needs role of application).

Then add the Azure Storage permission to API Permissions.

[image]

In addition, both `https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation` and `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` can be used for scope. For more details about Azure Storage resource ID(scope), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#azure-storage-resource-id).

The `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/.default` or `https://storage.azure.com/.default` are suitable for client credentials flow.

---

Steps:

1. Get authorization code in browser

Note: when azure account is signed in, you should accept Permissions requested.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client-id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44300/
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation
&state=12345
&prompt=consent
```

2. Get access token and refresh token. Try to decode the access token in https://jwt.io/, check the `aud`, and it looks like `https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net`.

[image]

3. Finally, test access token in your code.

[image]

Comment: I am able to ListContainer, ListBlobs, CreateContainer using that Bearer Token. But I am not able to Create a Blob, Delete a Blob, GetBlob are any special role or permission needed for them?

Comment: Hi, @MayankPatel. Do you add `Storage Blob Data Reader` role for your account?

Comment: No, I have added `Storage Blob Data Contributor` as the role. As shown in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: It's only for application, but not for signed-in user. Try to add `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the user, and test after about 10 mins. And I have added the role in my side! forget to check it:(

Comment: I tested without this role, it returned 403. It takes too much time to be effective. It's **important** to add the role for the user account.

Comment: I assigned the role to my signed-in email ID apart from the app and it ran successfully for all the requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since I crossed with the issue, please also ensure that your Shared Access Token (SAS) has the right permissions. I used READ permission instead of LIST for the list blob rest API. Just for the ppl who might face this problem.