# Specify Scope in Azure Storage Blob for REST requests while requesting token?

Tags: rest, scope, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rbac

Can anyone confirm that to make a REST requestd to Azure storage we have to do these steps?

1. Create an App Registration and get its `client ID` and `client secret`
2. Goto `API permissions` -> `Add permission` -> `Azure storage`, add `user_impersonation` as API permission that would allow the Application to access the Storage account on behalf of the signed-in user.
3. Goto `Access control IAM` -> `Add role` -> assign the given `signed-in user (email)` whichever role that you like.
4. Next you can now access the token to make the request.

In this logic, one has to grant the `read/write/complete-storage-account` access to the Role in step 3 and then impersonate that behavior to App created.

But let's say that I want to grant these levels of access while the token request. Shown in fig:
[image]

Can I do so? That I get these read/write/owner kind of different permissions while accessing the token.
If not then how can I manage different access levels?

- Should I use multiple users
- Should I use multiple applications

Comment: From your description, you want to get different tokens with different permissions?

Comment: Yes, something like that. What I want is that my customer doesn't have to create multiple users, apps to manage different roles/access(read/write/delete) on the Azure portal instead can I can do it for him through code using REST calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple applications, but multiple users are needed, when you use the *Delegated permission* `user_impersonation` of `Azure Storage` API i.e. `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` in the `scope`, the app will get all the permissions of the user in the storage account after user login. Besides, I notice you used `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation`, which just works for a specific storage account, make sure it meets your requirement.

Comment: In my last discussion with @PamelaPeng she suggested myaccount.blob.core.windows.net [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525481/authorization-permission-mismatch-when-trying-to-put-a-file-in-azure-blob-with-a) and it works for me so whats exactly difference between the two? Coming to the main question can I give read/write/owner access while generating access tokens or it can be done only through user_impersonation?

Comment: @MayankPatel 1.`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net` just works for one specific storage account, if it meets your scenario, just ignore it. 2.No, the permissions e.g. `read/write` is the action permission defined in the RBAC roles, when you request the token, we need to pass the permission exposed by the API i.e. user_impersonation, which means it can be done only through user_impersonation.